# Is it possible to modify core class in PHP?

Tags: php, php-7

I have to work with low-quality legacy PHP code. Because of poor architecture and exception handling, often happens, that an error (core `\Exception` or `\RuntimeException` or `\TypeError`) is thrown and caught at some moment, but ignored and instead replaced with hardcoded result, which hides original error. Because of high code duplication, it is hard to check all `catch`-blocks. Also, I can not just refactor all `catch`-blocks because of codebase size and VCS policy.

Thus, to debug errors, I'd like to replace core `\Exception::__construct` (and `\Error::__construct`) for runtime session on my local machine, so that every time any exception is created, my custom code was called (f.e. trigger error and use my error_handler). I do not want to simply override them in child classes, but replace in original core classes (maybe with ReflectionAPI?).

Please note: this is not about common question "how to convert errors to exceptions", but exactly vice versa.

Is it possible for PHP7.1 and higher?

Comment: You might want to try to [set a custom error handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

Comment: When exception is created, thrown and catched, the error is not triggered, so I can not handle it